# How to click an element which is visible only on mouse hover - selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

Note:

1. The code is written using angular on UI.
2. UI is like a chart - and I want to mouse hover  on top right corner and click on that blank space which will show me a dropdown.

Comment: Make element visible performing the mouse hover https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/mouse-hover-action/.

Comment: @pburgr not working already tried - the UI code is in angular and mouse hover is to be done 4 times at different places on a chart.

Comment: Please share html source code or url.

Answer (score 0):

If you directly use hover over on the invisble element, it won't work. you need to use hover over on parent element which is visible always.

**eg:** please see the 2 screenshot

**Before :**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

1. Here, I need to click the edit icon and delete icon
2. Both icons are not visible by default
3. but the (parent) whole first element box is visible.
4. I tried the mouse hover over on the serial number of first row.
5. So icons will be displayed
6. then, I clicked them

I hope this will be useful !

Comment: mouse hover is working for the 1st time by using movebyoffset. But it is not working for the 2nd time on another chart. And no parent element is available.

Answer (score 0):

used movebyoffset as element was not visible directly due to angular.
Searched it on intenet no one answered this.

always use movebyoffset if code is in angular. And then use action class to build and perform click.
For getting exact x & y cords use this tool - chorme web app -> coordinates.

example: